# Factoring two matrices into shared and unique variance

Tags: structural-equation-modeling

I have two square symmetric matrices, A and B, each of which contains the pairwise cosine distances between two different sets of vectors. The sets of vectors are different for A and B, but they are correlated. The original vectors from which these distance matrices were constructed are no longer available. These matrices are not positive definite.

I would like to factor A and B into AB, A1 and B1. AB would contain the shared variance between A and B, whereas A1 and B1 would contain the unique and error variance of A and B respectively.

If I project the singular values of A and B into the space of orthogonal bases of A and B and then create a pairwise distance matrix for all of said bases, only the first few bases are correlated. In other words, only the first few principal components of A and B appear to have significant shared variance, if that helps.

Comment: But what is your question? The shared variance should be grasped by the canonical correlations.